# Adding default sorting arrows to GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm new to Asp.net and I'm currently working with GridViews.  I've looked around this site and others have seen tips for how to add sorting arrows to column headers.

So far I've done this:

Set these GridView properties:

```
SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortasc"
SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortdesc"
```

And my css has this:

```
th.sortasc a  
{
   display:block; padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
   background:url("images/icons/ascArrow.png") no-repeat;
}

th.sortdesc a 
{
   display:block; padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
  background:url("images/icons/descArrow.png") no-repeat;
}
```

This works great to show an image after the user clicks a header and the column sorts.

The issue I'm having now, is that I'd like the columns to show images by default so that users can know that they can click them to sort.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can show the arrow for sorting behavior of a `gridview` column in the `RowCreated` event something like this i usually do it this way

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (tc.HasControls())
            {
                // search for the header link
                LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)tc.Controls[0];
                if (lnk != null && GridView1.SortExpression == lnk.CommandArgument)
                {
                    // inizialize a new image
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    // setting the dynamically URL of the image
                    img.ImageUrl = "~/img/ico_" + (GridView1.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "asc" : "desc") + ".gif";
                    // adding a space and the image to the header link
                    tc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" "));
                    tc.Controls.Add(img);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it also toggles the image on ascending and descending sort orders of column

What the code actually do is it
loops through the GridView Header to search a `LinkButton` **(the Framework creates it only if the `SortExpression` property is set)**. Then, if the found `LinkButton` is the sorted field, then it shows the image to the output, that's all

[AnswerSource](http://blog.devexperience.net/en/2/Display_an_arrow_in_the_header_of_GridView.aspx)

Comment: You could actually move the initialization of img into the if statement, and combine the if statements. `if (lnk != null && GridView1.SortExpression == lnk.CommandArgument) {...`

Comment: @ Patrick  see the edit and thanks for suggesting the improvement

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'll try this out.  I have a couple of questions though: Are there parts of this I'd have to change for VB instead of C#? Also, I haven't worked with events for controls yet, I'm pretty new to this.  Any tips of where to go to edit the rowcreated event of a gridview?

Comment: select gridview in designer and go to properties window in this window you will find RowCreated just double click on that and you will get RowCreated event created for you then replace the control ids with the ids you provided to your controls

Comment: Thanks Devjosh! I was able to get to the RowCreated event.  I tried to convert what you wrote into VB but it's not working for me.  I'm getting an error message at the "?" in the img line.  Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Ok, nevermind I got it to work.  It now shows the image on the column I sort on.  I was trying to show images before they sort though so that users see up or down arrows and know that they can sort

Answer (score 2):

I used the following method... Same as accepted answer but using characters instead of images. Sharing in case it helps someone else.

```
protected void GrdOverview_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (tc.HasControls())
            {
                // search for the header link
                LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)tc.Controls[0];

                string sortDir = ViewState["SortDirection"] != null ? ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString() : "ASC";
                string sortBy = ViewState["SortExpression"] != null ? ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString() : "---";

                if (lnk != null && sortBy == lnk.CommandArgument)
                {
                    string sortArrow = sortDir == "ASC" ? " &#9650;" : " &#9660;";
                    lnk.Text += sortArrow;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I reset it? Suppose I have a separate DropDownList (DDL). The initial gridview is displayed and let's say I sort Column #3. If I select a different item in DDL, a new set of data is displayed without any specific order in the gridview. However, the arrow still stays in Column #3. How can I remove the arrow to tell the user that none of them are sorted?

Answer (score 0):

From your question:"To show images by default so that users can know that they can click them to sort." 
Add a `HeaderStyle-CssClass` property to your gridview, and put the default style in that property:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        AllowSorting="True"
                        OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass ="headRowSortable">
```

...and add corrosponding CSS with your Up-Down sortable icon:

```
.headRowSortable > th > a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 15px;
        background: url('../Images/up-down-sort.png') left center no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: central;
    }
```

Which will work great as long as you are using an `<asp:SQLDataSource>`...which I am guessing you are.

As soon as you start binding the DataGrid to a Data Source in code, the GridView will stop applying the `SortedAscendingHeaderStyle` and `SortedDescendingHeaderStyle` because it won't know which column got sorted which way.

So in the case that you are doing your own data binding, you need to change the classes on the columns during the `GridView_Sorting` event:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            //get the index of the column we sorted.
            int iSortedColIdx = 0;
            foreach (DataControlField c in GridView1.Columns)
            {
                if (c.SortExpression == e.SortExpression)
                    break;
                iSortedColIdx++;
            }

            string sSortDirection = "";
            if ((string)ViewState["SortColumn"] == e.SortExpression)
                sSortDirection = ((string)ViewState["SortDirection"] == "") ? " DESC" : "";
            else
                ViewState["SortColumn"] = e.SortExpression;

            ViewState["SortDirection"] = sSortDirection;


            DataTable oDT = (DataTable)ViewState["MyDataSource"];
            if (oDT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string sSortString = e.SortExpression + sSortDirection;
                oDT.DefaultView.Sort = sSortString;

                GridView1.DataSource = oDT;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                // SET THE HEADER CSSCLASS AFTER THE DATA BIND. IT'LL GET CLEARED ON DATA BIND.
                GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[iSortedColIdx].CssClass = sSortDirection == "" ? "headRowSortAsc" : "headRowSortDesc";
            }

        }
```

... and the corrosponding css:

```
th.headRowSortAsc a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: url("../Images/down-sort.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px;
    background-size: contain;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: central;
}

th.headRowSortDesc a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: url("../Images/up-sort.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px;
    background-size: contain;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: central;
}
```